# what is the good way to optimize the list objects while the object take off more memory space than data itself in python

Tags: python, string, list

what is the good way to optimize the list objects while the object take off more memory space than data itself in python?

suppose we have 100M string list objects (which could from long_string.split('\t')), and each string object hold only several bytes of string data, but the object it self takes dozens of memory. what is the good alternative solutions here in python?

Comment: What are you asking? Are you asking what data structure would be the most efficient to store many (100-million in your example) objects (strings)?

Comment: Yes, If there is one.

Comment: It depends on your application. Do you really need to store the elements in memory? Will you be iterating over the entire dataset once? More than once? The existing generator-answers might be best for some cases, but might not work for some applications. What is your application doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def split_lines(text):
    temp = ''
    for char in text:
        if (char != '\n'):
            temp += char
        else:
            yield temp
            temp = ''
for each in split_lines(text):
     #process each line
```

I check, this works, bug it seems to take longer than just use

```
for each in text.split('\n'):
    #process each line
```

But it saves a lot of memory space since there are billions of lines in the text data!

Comment: `split_lines()` might be a better name (your code splits `text` into several lines; it doesn't split *a line*). [You don't need to load the whole file in memory at once (as `text`) to process lines in it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16057600/4279).

Answer (score 3):

A good approach might be to not store them in memory at once, for example by having a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) that would produce the objects on demand.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is that you read the whole file in memory, if possible you should read the file in chunks and process them

```
file_object = open('filename', 'r')

while True:
    line = file_object.readline()
    if not line: break
    process_line(line)
```

Comment: This is a solution, of course. However, I think this will cost many I/O operations.. The point would be, I can afford to load all data ( only hundreds MBs), but I might not afford to split the text to billions of string object (which will cost GBs of memory space, several times more than the original data). So loading data to the memory and use generator to handle may be the most efficient way.

Comment: you could write it as `for line in file_object: process_line(line)`

Comment: @chentingpc did you try to measure the elapsed time using this approach ? btw, you can also fetch bigger batches if you want to increase IO speed

Answer (score 0):

To process one line at a time from a big file with many lines:

```
def main():
    with open('input_file.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            process_line(line)
```

If the file contains numbers (e.g., one short integer per line) and you need all of them then you could use [numpy arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/whatisnumpy.html):

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import imap
import numpy as np

def count_lines(file):
    """Return number of lines in the file."""
    return sum(chunk.count('\n') for chunk in iter(partial(file.read, 1<<15),''))

with open('input_file.txt', 'rb') as file:
    nlines = count_lines(file) # count lines to avoid overallocation in fromiter
    file.seek(0) # rewind
    a = np.fromiter(imap(int, file), dtype=np.int16, count=nlines)
```